# Why is Bash not allowing me to enter input at prompts?

Tags: bash

For some reason, my Macbook bash terminal is not allowing me to enter "y" from a prompt.
I'm not really sure how to describe this, but you can see the action below.

```
$ sudo pip uninstall django  

Password:  
Uninstalling Django:  

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/django-admin.py  
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg-info  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django  

Proceed (y/n)? **y^M^?^?^?^M^M^M^M^M^C**Your response ('y\r\x7f\x7f\x7f') was not one of the expected responses: y, n

Proceed (y/n)? y^M^C^D^M^M^M^M^CYour response ('y\r\x04') was not one of the expected responses: y, n  

Proceed (y/n)? Y^M^Xc^C^D^CYour response ('y\r\x18c') was not one of the expected responses: y, n  

Proceed (y/n)? ^D^CYour response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? ^COperation cancelled by user
```

Comment: Can you copy `y` from a different window (maybe together with a newline) and paste it to the terminal?

Comment: Try y^J, or the y key followed by Control-J?

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-J worked, as did opening a new terminal window.